# how to count messages for mailboxer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi am using merit to grant badges to users that send messages through mailbox.
i have setup mailboxer and its working fine in which users can have a conversation and send messages to each other.
from that i added merit to grant badges to users that send message like this

```
grant_on 'messages#create',  badge: 'Engraved Glass', to: :user do    |message|
    message.user.messages.count >= 50
end
```

but when ever i create new message i get this error

```
undefined method `user' for true:TrueClass
```

but when its sending message on a old conversation it doesnt throw this error

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky.  When you're working with a more straighforward setup, for example a Comment model, with a comments_controller and a @comment object, then what you're proposing would be fine.  But because this is a messages_controller, who knows what your mailboxer object is called and :user isn't an attribute on the object anyway.. it all goes amuck.

But we can fix it.  There's a couple of rules here if the model and controller are not the same.

1. Make sure you define an object.  Mailboxer expects the messages_controller to define a @message object - So in your create action of messages make sure that you set it `@message =  current_user.send_message(to_user, params[:message][:message_body],params[:message][:subject])` - must be an instance variable using the @ sign
2. Make sure you set the proper attribute for a user.  In your case, with Mailboxer, it's going to be `:receiver`
3. Since `:receiver` doesn't align directly to a model, give it the model name `model_name` "User"

So now your grant will look more like

```
grant_on 'messages#create', badge: 'Engraved Glass', to: :receiver, model_name: "User" do |message|
 message.receiver.messages.count >= 50
end
```

Comment: well in my message#create controller i have it like this  `    recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
        conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
        flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
        redirect_to conversation_path(conversation) ` so how can i archive it base on your suggestion @trh

Comment: Like I had said about the expectation of the naming convention, it expects messages_controller to render a `@message` object - in an instance variable, you instead have a `conversation` object in a local variable.  So change conversation to `@message` and then in your redirect change also make the same change

Comment: have done that but none of them is granted the badge, i only want the sender to be granted a badge not the reciver

Comment: `messages` returns the receipt, it's like saying this is a sent message.  So the `receiver` of a sent message is actually the person who sent it.  -- confusing, i know :)  but if you inspect one of the objects (user.messages.first.inspect) - it will look something like Mailboxer::Receipt id: 114, receiver_id: 1, receiver_type: "User", notification_id: 57, is_read: true, trashed: false, deleted: false, mailbox_type: "sentbox", created_at: "2016-04-08 17:54:53", updated_at: "2016-04-08 17:54:53" -- you'll notice there isn't both a sender and receiver, because this is only the sender side